# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.5.0

Tags: android, gradle, geofire

When I add the following dependency in my gradle:

```
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.5.0'
}
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.5.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

[I tried to install a previous version (1.4.0)](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) but was met with the same error.

Is there any way around this?

[Here is the package in question](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android)

Comment: Did you add the Jitpack repository to your root’s `build.gradle` as what ofri cofri has stated?

Comment: I did not...I've added it and it now works. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you enabled Jitpack in your project? This is needed, along with the 'implementation' code that you showed up here.
https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android#enable-jitpack

**Enable Jitpack**
Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: No I didn't! Thankyou that was the problem

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have added the repository as said
`buildscript { repositories { maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } }`
but Im still cant shake the error
`ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.5.0 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34564787)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).